# sampling mechanism for correlated variables

Tags: distributions, sampling, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo

Assuming `Y=f(x1,..,Xn)`, while doing `Monte Carlo` simulation, I need to sample `x1, ..xn` based on their probabilistic distribution. However, these xi are correlated with each other. What are the available sampling mechanisms for this kind of scenario?

Comment: Generating or simulating from a multivariate distribution is standard, see e.g. [Devroye's reference book.](https://amzn.to/2GaBdG9) But the question is unclear as to whether you want correlation or you need to handle correlated simulations (with an `MCMC` tag that is not directly connected with the question).

Comment: what is n? Is it number of simulations or dimensionality of the factors?

Comment: n is the dimensionality of the factors